# Do I need to do anything when I create my own internal packages for my Android code?

Tags: android

I am refactoring my code, and I am organizing my classes into packages. But I find that my program doesn't run when I create my own subpackages (Java, not android, packages). Is there anything special I need to do if I have several internal packages in my code?

Comment: Have you adjusted you imports after moving your classes into different packages?

Comment: Yes, I have. I use eclipse to auto-import for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only Android-specific change you should have to make is updating your `AndroidManifest` to use the full class names (e.g. `com.example.ClassName`). Post your errors if this doesn't fit it.

(Of course, you will also need to change the `imports` just like in any other Java application.)

Comment: Still get a runtime error. The only class referred to in my manifest file is my Activity class. Changing it to the fully qualified name doesn't help :(

Comment: If you post the error, I might be able to help. As it is, I really have no idea.